# SQL Server DB is not accessible in WCF Service

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, exception, authorization

I created edmx Entity framework file to map the table from my Database Herbalshop. In my WCF service i created object context and try to run the query which retrieve first record. 
When i try to run my WCF service i am getting the error as ACCESS is DENIED. but i am the owner of Herbalshop database. 
I tried to debug my service and got the error as:

> System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: what is the exact message of the error?

Comment: Are you connecting to a proper SQL DB or a compact SQL DB? whats the connectio string like? If its a DB server, is it on the same server as the wcf service?

Comment: Do the SQL server allow user name login?  If you try that.

Answer (score 0):

Account you're running your web service under must have Server and Database Connection Permissions.

Comment: Error message is "Access is denied" in WCFTestClient screen. I am using proper SQL server 2005 with windows authentication. connectin string in EF is metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=HerbalShop;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True".                               DB and WCF service and client applicatin all are in the machine in the same windows authentication

Comment: @user1468128: Under what account does the service's app pool run? You can check that in IIS snap-in.

Comment: Provider Management  
Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

Comment: I thought aspnet_regsql was to configure memebership services this does not make sense to me.